# NoMethodError (Undefined Method For 'admin_application_path')

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, methods, controller, undefined

We've been building an Admin system, and recently we added a Javascript file which makes the rows in our tables clickable. We added ths link into a partial, which we've called in the Admin Index file to make the rows clickable but now when we want to go on Admin Index we keep getting this error:

> NoMethodError In Admin::Application#index
>
> Undefined method `admin_application_path' for '#Admin::ApplicationController

Here is the code we have in our partial:

```
    <tbody>
    <% collection.each do |resource| %>
        <tr data-link="<%= resource_path(resource) %>">
            <% model.attribute_names.each do |attr| %>
                <td><%= resource.send(attr) %></td>
            <% end %>
            <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_resource_path(resource) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to "Delete", resource_path(resource), :method => :delete, data: { "confirm" => "Are you sure?" } %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

When on the error page the following code snippet in highlighted:

```
<tr data-link="<%= resource_path(resource) %>">
```

The following is a helper that we have in place too:

```
#Admin Variable Paths
def admin_variable_path(controller)
    {:controller => "admin/#{controller}", :action => :index}
end
```

I'm not sure whether I've added everything, but if there's anything that you need to see or know, then I'll add it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use the Rails [polymorphic_path](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) helper for this:

```
<tr data-link="<%= polymorphic_path([:admin, resource]) %>">
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only works for the <tr data-link="<%= resource_path(resource) %>">.

Comment: You may wish to use the `edit_polymorphic_path` helper to generate `edit` URLs, like this: <%= edit_polymorphic_path([:admin, resource])  %>

Comment: You can use the standard polymorphic path for the delete link, because that's defined with the `:method => :delete` attribute